# Django : calling an model's instance.save() from within another model's save

Tags: python, django, orm, model, save

I have models like :

```
class A(models.Model):

    b = ForeignKey(B,unique=True, db_index=True)
    #other fields

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(A,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
        self.b.some_field = 'value'
        self.b.save()

class B(models.Model):

    #fields here
```

The problem here is when I save `A's` value and hit save (either from admin or from the shell) The value of the corresponding `B` instace (i.e `self.b`) save does not get called. The object `b` is not getting the value `value` it is supposed to get.

What is going on here ?

Comment: That should work. Can you provide a real example?

Comment: `self=super(A,self).save(*args,**kwargs)` should work

Comment: Don'y you need to create a B instance before trying to save it?